# Does it hurt SEO if the most common phrases on the site are common eCommerce actions such as "add to cart"?

Tags: seo, keywords, shopping-cart

A site for evaluating SEO tells me that my site's most common 2 - 3 word phrase is "add to cart", and in the top 7 I have 3 other phrases that contain "add" and "cart" such as "wooden add"  "kennel cart".

Does this hurt my SEO? This is a new site that I'm fighting to bring up on google.bg to a reasonable standing, to no avail for 3 months. Could a part of the problem be that Google is indexing my add to cart buttons?

Could I display the add to cart from javascript, since I am afraid it could lead to some cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: Search is not about keywords. It is about whole language. Create your content well and do not worry about trivialities.

Comment: As a side note, most of the online SEO sites are junk. They just want your attention and are willing to propagate a falsehood for your attention. This is how they make money. Pay attention to Google Analytics and use a log file analyzer such as Piwik. These tell you much of what you need to know. If you want a decent online tool, Semrush is as good as they get. But take it with salt.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for the heads up ! One thing I did notice is that other sites similar to mine have above 1000 keywords and I only have 24 keywords/phrases.  Should I aim for more than hundreds and maybe thousands somehow or does it not matter? We are talking about an online shop here so I am guessing more is better right ?

Also, this Piwik needs to be installed on the server, but I am using a paid hosting solution, how can I use it in that case?

Comment: Again, search is not about keywords or search term matches. That s not how it works. Piwik can be installed on the server without issue or on a desktop and simply move your log files over. There is no substitute for examining your log activity with a good analyzer.